# Netgear WN3000RP-200PES Universal Wi-Fi Range Extender - issues connecting from laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wireless-router

I have a `Dell Inspiron 5370` which has the `Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter`. I have a `TP-Link TL-WR841N 300Mbps Wireless-N Router` in the other room.

My earlier `Thinkpad` used to get the wifi signals fine even in my other room. But the Dell couldn't. So I purchased the `Netgear` Wifi Extender & set it up with the same SSID - so that the laptop seamlessly works when I move it across rooms. This worked fine for a month. But since then I am facing issues - my laptop tries to connect to the extender but fails & then goes back to connecting to the router whose signal is too weak & hence unusable. I have to turn the extender on 2-3 times & also disconnect/connect to the SSID 2-3 times on the laptop before it successfully connects to the extender. The extender is very close to the laptop so it's not a signal strength problem. All the lights on the extender also seem to be fine/same when it does connect to the extender & when it doesn't. I have even done a factory reset of the extender but the problem continues. I think the Extender says "No internet" & hence the laptop goes back to connect to the main router, but I am not 100% sure about this.

I have latest firmware on both the wifi adapter & the extender.

Is there a way, I can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the Extender?

Comment: @harrymc - do you mean replace with a different extender? No - it's a new extender - less than 2 months month & I don't have another one.

Comment: Try to factory reset it, but if it cannot connect to the router then something is wrong in hardware, or conditions have changed such as new interference.

Comment: @harrymc - Already mentioned it in my original question - I did do a factory reset & try but no difference. Also as I have mentioned in the original question, it's not as if I am never able to connect - after turning the extender on/off 2/3 times & also turning wifi on/off on the laptop 2/3 times, I am able to connect.

Comment: You mentioned a reset on the laptop only. To be sure: Does it help if you just turn on/off a few times the extender or only the laptop? Was there a driver update of the computer wifi card (check in Device Manager)?

Comment: @harrymc - sorry - that was a mistake - I did a factory reset of the extender not the laptop - I will edit it in the question. Both the extender and the laptop's wifi card have the latest firmware.

Comment: Could you do the test of power off/on only one, to try to better place where is the problem?

Comment: @harrymc - I didn't power off laptop at all. I power off the extended a couple of times & then have to enable/disable wifi on laptop a few times before it starts working.

Comment: Is it enough to only disable/enable wifi on the laptop multiple times?

Comment: @harrymc - sometimes yes, sometimes no. I haven't been able to find any pattern.

Comment: Does rebooting the laptop help?

Comment: @harrymc - no, rebooting doesn't help

Comment: Summing up the information, it looks more like your laptop wifi is glitching. The only way to test is to use a usb wifi adapter and see.

Comment: @harrymc - I also tried with my phone today & that seems to experience the same issue. So I think it's likely with the extender

Comment: We return back to my first comment, to replace the Extender. If it's still under warranty it should be simple.

Comment: @harrymc - It's not worth the time & money I would spend going to the warranty center, reproducing the problem for them etc. I am looking for a way to troubleshoot - any logs from the wifi driver etc?

Comment: Logs would require SSH into the extender and trafficking with its Linux setup (if it's on Linux), which might be taken as an excuse to void the warranty. Borrow an extender from a friend or something, or the vendor might accept a replacement without question. You could also when this happens look on the router to see if the extender is still attached to it or has disconnected.

Comment: Have you logged-in into the modem when this happens to see if the extender is still attached? And coming to think of it: Why do you expect the extender to pick up the modem when your computer that is just next to it can't? No reason for the extender to do any better than the computer.

Comment: @harrymc - yes the extender is attached to the modem. It's a little closer to the modem & also the laptop's wifi card is well known to have poor range - even my phone does better.

Comment: Is the extender connected by wifi or cable? Cable is preferable for good results. If you are using wifi for the connection, try another wifi channel (11 is usually recommended).

Comment: @harrymc Extender connected by Wifi. Channel is set to Auto on the router. Channel cannot be changed on the extender - it just uses same channel as router, I think.

Comment: Set to 11 on the router.

Comment: Even better than setting it to 11, do a wireless network analysis using something like NetStumbler and set it to the most uncongested channel that does not overlap with heavily congested ones. Note that all of [1,6,11] are non-overlapping channels.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off getting a new router that supports multi-band AC with multiple beam forming antennas. The reason is that adding an extender contributes to noise in the air and could result in worse performance if radio smog was the original problem you were facing.

I recommend you perform a site survey. You can use WiFi Analyzer for free on your phone or computer:

Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en_US

Windows: 
https://matthafner.com/wifianalyzer/

This will tell you how many other devices are broadcasting on each channel and you can also measure signal strength of your APs from various important locations around the house.

If you find that your AP or signal extender are using a noisy channel you could look to manually configure the channels they use. A modern AC router will often pick the best channel when set to auto but those old N routers might need to be manually set if they are not finding a good channel.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to my question at all. I could buy a new router or a new laptop or a new extender. But here what I am looking for is a way to troubleshoot - why it works sometimes & doesn't work at other times.

Comment: WiFi Analyzer is how you can troubleshoot. Did you finish reading?